# zend framework 2 User class not found

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm working on a ZF2 class for insert Users info throw a form. I have a User class, UserTable class and I've made some changes to my controller.

```
***User.php***
 <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Users\Model;

/**
 * Description of User
 *
 * @author mlorente
 */
class User {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    public function setPassword($clear_password) {
        $this->password = md5($clear_password);
    }

    function exchangeArray($data){
        $this->name = (isset($data['name']))?$data['name']:null;
        $this->password = (isset($data['email']))?$data['email']:null;
        if (isset($data['password'])){
            $this->setPassword($data['password']);
        }
    }
}
```

***UserTable.php***

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Users\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

/**
 * Description of userTable
 *
 * @author mlorente
 */
class UserTable {

    protected $tableGateway;

    function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function saveUser(User $user){

        $data = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => $user->password,
        );

        $id = (int)$user->id;

        if($id == 0){
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        }else{
            if($this->getUser($id)){
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            }else{
                throw new Exception('El ID de usuario no existe');
            }
        }
    }

    public function getUser ($id){
        $id = (int)$id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row){
            throw new Exception('No se ha encontrado la fila con ID '.$id);
        }

        return $row;
    }

}
```

***RegisterController.php***

```
public function processAction(){
        $form = new RegisterForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Enviar');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if(!$request->isPost()){
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL,
                    array('controller' => 'register',
                          'action' => 'index'));
        }

        $registro = new Register();
        $form->setInputFilter($registro->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if($form->isValid()){
            $registro->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->createUser($form->getData());
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL, array('controller' => 'register','action' => 'confirm'));
        }else{
            $model = new ViewModel(array(
                'error' => true,
                'form' => $form,
            ));
            $model->setTemplate('users/register/index');
            return $model;
        }

        return array('form' => $form);
    }

    protected function createUser(array $data){

        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
        $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

        $user = new User();
        $user->exchangeArray($data);
        $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
        $userTable->saveUser($user);
        return true;
    }
```

Las piece of code is the part for the controller. When I test the app, it mentions this error

> Fatal error: Class 'Users\Controller\User' not found in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\ZF2_TUTORIAL1\module\Users\src\Users\Controller\RegisterController.php
>   on line 74

I'm looking for this line but I don't know how to fix it. I think is mor simple than it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you (presumably) declared the namespace `Users\Controller` at the top of your controller class, when you call `new User();` PHP thinks you mean `new \Users\Controller\User()`, which doesn't exist (hence the error). To fix this you import the user model into the current scope. You need to do the same for `UserTable` as well or you'll have the same issue with that.

Add these two lines to the top of your controller class (after the namespace declaration):

```
use Users\Model\User;
use Users\Model\UserTable;
```

Then it should work.